# Azure Web App Deployment Slots - where did the balancing go?

Tags: azure, load-balancing, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment-slots

I vividly remember being able to balance traffic between two deployment slots.

Has this feature been removed? As it's no longer in the deployment slot blade.

What would be the lowest cost (time & infrastructure) approach to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it might have been available under deployment slots in the past, you can now find this functionality under **Testing in production**. It still depends on using deployment slots, but the settings for balancing have a separate menu entry on the portal now.

Here's an article that will explain how to get things running: [A/B Testing with Azure Websites](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tomholl/2014/11/09/ab-testing-with-azure-websites/)